# How to read a long int via i2c?

Tags: python, i2c, arduino

I tried to connect an Arduino Uno with my Raspberry using the i2c bus, with code and wiring suggested [here](http://blog.oscarliang.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-connected-i2c/). This example is sending only one byte from RPi to Arduino and back, and everything works fine.

Now, since I need to send a larger number (which is a value from the ultrasonic sensor on Arduino) to RPi, I edited the code, but I just receive zeros. I was reading on the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/WireWrite) of the `Wire.h` library (Arduino side) and the `smbus` python module (RPi side) but I haven't spotted anything helpful.
What I try to do is to send 4 bytes one by one and then read them using `struct.unpack`

This is the code on Arduino

```
/*
 i2c
  pin A4   SDA (raspi pin3)
  pin A5   SCL (raspi pin5)

 */
#include <Wire.h>
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x04

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600); // start serial for output

  // initialize i2c as slave
  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); // register event
  Serial.println("Ready!");
}

void loop() {     
  delay(500);
}

void requestEvent()
{
  long d;
  d=10; // mockup value, in the real script is acquired by the sensor
  Serial.println(d);
  Wire.write((const uint8_t*)&d, sizeof(long));
}
```

And this is the script on RPi

```
import smbus
import time
import struct
# for RPI version 1, use "bus = smbus.SMBus(0)"
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# This is the address we setup in the Arduino Program
address = 0x04

def readLong():
   #number = bus.read_byte(address)
   number=""
   for i in xrange(4):
      number += chr(bus.read_byte(address))
   return struct.unpack('l', number)

while True:
   time.sleep(1)
   number = readLong()
   print "[Arduino]", number, "mm"
```

Comment: Why use the Arduino at all the Pi is capable of reading the sensor directly?

Comment: It is a requirement, being part of a larger university project, I cannot change this design choice.

Comment: The Arduino must act as a slave.  You can't just call Wire.write every half a second.  You must only write in response to a read request from the Pi.

Comment: @joan I fixed the Arduino code, it is now acting as a slave, but I still didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution uses `read_i2c_block_data`, triggering only one request event for the slave.
Code for the slave (Arduino):

```cpp
void sendData(){
  long n;
  n = 300; //mockup
  //n = readDistance();
  Wire.write((const uint8_t*)&n, sizeof(long));
  //Serial.print(n);
  //Serial.println(" mm");
}
```

Code for the master (RPi):

```
def readLong():
   block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 0) #second arg is 'cmd'. It is andatory but not used in this case. It may be used by the higher level protocol
   # block is a list of 32 elements (int)
   #return block
   n = struct.unpack('<l', ''.join([chr(i) for i in block[:4]]))[0]
   return n
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't afford to waste time in an interrupt service routine.  Especially with a protocol like I2C or SPI as a slave where you must respond at the master's clock rate.

Either remove `Serial.println` or at the very least move it to after the `Wire.write`

```c
void requestEvent()
{
  long d;
  d=10; // mockup value, in the real script is acquired by the sensor
  Serial.println(d);
  Wire.write((const uint8_t*)&d, sizeof(long));
}
```

I think you need to read 4 bytes in 1 I2C transaction.  You probably need to use the `read_i2c_block_data` call.  Doing it as 4 separate calls probably triggers 4 separate `requestEvent` on the Arduino.

```py
for i in xrange(4):
   number += chr(bus.read_byte(address))
```

Comment: yes indeed, it triggers 4 separate requestEvent

Comment: What are the parameters of `read_i2c_block_data`? (can't find the python doc)

Comment: @g.tataranni The best I can find is http://wiki.erazor-zone.de/wiki:linux:python:smbus:doc

Answer (score 1):

I have an ugly solution, but working.

On Arduino:

```
long n;
int req=0;
void sendData(){
  if(req==0){
    n = 300; //mockup
    //n = readDistance();
  }
  Serial.print(n);
  Serial.println(" xx");
  Wire.write(n);
  n = n>>8;
  req = (req+1)%4;
}
```

On Raspberry

```
def readLong():
   number=""
   for _ in xrange(4):
      number += chr(bus.read_byte(address))
   return struct.unpack('<l', number)[0]
```

I know it can be improved and I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 0):

this does not works for me but this works

```
def readLong():
   block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 1) #second arg is 'cmd'. It is andatory but not used in this case. It may be used by the higher level protocol
   n=struct.unpack('<l',bytes(block[:4]))[0]
   return n
```

Comment: This works and doesn't work?

Comment: Please clarify your answer: what doesn't work and how.