# RasPi 3 - Arduino Uno I2C communication - Block transfer error

Tags: pi-3, i2c, arduino

I am trying to connect an Arduino Uno with my Raspberry using the i2c bus, based on the tutorial given [here](https://oscarliang.com/raspberry-pi-arduino-connected-i2c/), sending only one byte from RPi to Arduino and back. I was able to implement this and it works fine.

I needed to transfer more than a byte of data, so I referred to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45266/how-to-read-a-long-int-via-i2c/55754?noredirect=1#comment84731_55754) page and tried to implement the given solution with python 3.4.2. However when I implement the solution, it gives me following error:

```
>>>
[45, 0, 25, 2, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/codeSampleMaster2.py", line 15, in <module>
    number = readLong()
  File "/home/pi/codeSampleMaster2.py", line 10, in readLong
    n = struct.unpack('<l',(''.join([chr(i) for i in block[:4]])))[0]
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

The data in the square bracket is what I received as part of block read. What I require is to be able to extract 45002502 as part of my program.

Please guide me as to where I might have made a mistake. Im fairly new to working with python and Rasp Pi.

Arduino Code:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x04
int senseLeft = A0;     // Left side distance sensor input pin.
long senseLeftVal = 0;   // Variable to store the Left side sensor value.

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600); // start serial for output 
  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); // register event
  Serial.println("Ready!");
}

void loop() {
//  Serial.println(senseLeftVal);
  delay(1);
}

void requestEvent()
{
  senseLeftVal = analogRead(senseLeft);
  Wire.write((const uint8_t*)&senseLeftVal, sizeof(long));
  Serial.println(senseLeftVal);
}
```

Rasp Pi Code:

```python
import smbus
import time
import struct

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x04

def readLong():
    block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0)
    print(block)
    n = struct.unpack('<l',(''.join([chr(i) for i in block[:4]])))[0]
    return n

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    number = readLong()
    print("Arduino: ", number)
```

Comment: It would be simplest just to use Python 2 rather than Python 3.

Comment: I can try it in Python 2, however, all other modules have been implemented in Python 3. How can I use Python 2 files in a Python 3 project?

Comment: Just do what Shreyas Murali suggests. Replace the struct.unpack line with `n = block[0] | block[1] << 8 | block[2] <<16 | block[3] << 24` which should give the correct answer.

Comment: @joan when I implement the solution mentioned I am able to OR two bytes of data at a time `block[0] | block[1] << 8` and `block[2] | block[3] << 8`. Any additional byte changes the output to random numbers.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to include in your question the result of print(block) together with the number you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling the following line is the problem

```
n = struct.unpack('<l',(''.join([chr(i) for i in block[:4]])))[0]
```

try replacing it with this

```
n = block[0] << 24 | block[1] << 16 | block[2] << 8 | block[3]
print(n)
```

if the numbers dont make sense, you might need to swap the order like so (for endianess)

```
n = block[3] << 24 | block[2] << 16 | block[1] << 8 | block[0]
print(n)
```

and check again

---

Also as joan suggests in [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45266/how-to-read-a-long-int-via-i2c?answertab=active#tab-top) post, you might want move the `analogRead` after the `Wire.write` to reduce the chances of missed communication as timing is critical in dealing with i2c devices. Ideally you'd want to move the `analogRead` into the `loop` and simply send out the last read value when requested in the event handler

---

Looking at the documentation and example for smbus over [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smbus2/0.1.2) it makes sense that you are getting 32 bytes of data

> Example 2: Read a block of data
>   Note: You can read up to 32 bytes at once.

```
from smbus2 import SMBusWrapper    
with SMBusWrapper(1) as bus:
# Read a block of 16 bytes from address 80, offset 0    
block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(80, 0, 16) # Returned value is a list of 16 bytes    
print(block)
```

Since you are only sending 4 bytes = (sizeof(long)) from your arduino, there are 28 bytes filled with junk (255 in your case). the simplest fix is just use the first 4 bytes like so

```
import smbus
import time
import struct

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x04

def readLong():
    block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0)
    print(block) # should print the array with 32 entries

    reading = block[0:4] # select only first 4 bytes
    print(reading)

    n = reading[0] << 24 | reading[1] << 16 | reading[2] << 8 | reading[3]
    print(n)

    return n

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    number = readLong()
    print("Arduino: ", number)
```

---

Comment: Considering joans suggestion I had kept the printing statements after the `Write.write` is executed. Also, I tried implementing your solution but in either case the output value of `n`doesn't make sense. Is it like there is a type change when i link the `block` data to `n`?

Comment: I am currently using **smbus** rather than **smbus2** as indicated in the documentation. Also, when i implement your solution, the result is as follows: Output of `print(reading)` is `[62, 0, 53, 0]`. However the output of `print(n)` is `1040200960`.

Comment: Reversing the statement of n as `reading[3] << 24 | reading[2] << 16 | reading[1] << 8 | reading[0]` also gives junk value at output. However, i was able to merge 2 bytes just like before as commented above.

Comment: According to the documentation [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogRead) the function `analogRead` returns a int between 0 and 1023 which means you should get only values between [0,0,0,0] and [0,0,3,255]. In your case you are getting [62,0,53,0] which is quite puzzling as no combination of those numbers will give 0<= value <= 1023. Recommend trying the following: (a) comment out `Serial.println(senseLeftVal);` (b) send a fixed number from the arduino and verify you get the expected value on the pi. if the fixed number comes through ok, then `analogRead` needs to be looked at.

Comment: I found my mistake. I was trying to use a different analog port pin and forgot to comment previous pin. After making corrections, I was able to receive correct output.