# Understanding struct.unpack code

Tags: python, i2c

Hello great community of helpers!
We new programmers greatly appreciate your continuous help.  Thank You!

Can you explain this 1 line of code below... -  Or break it down into separate chunks.  I read the documentation, and am still a little foggy.

```
n = struct.unpack('<l', ''.join([chr(i) for i in block[:4]]))[0]
```

For reference, Here is all the relative code from another working snippet from [Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45266/how-to-read-a-long-int-via-i2c/55754?noredirect=1#comment84731_55754).  This is an Arduino sending a long int over i2c to a raspberry pi.
Raspberry Pi Code:

```
import smbus
import time
import struct
# for RPI version 1, use "bus = smbus.SMBus(0)"
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# This is the address we setup in the Arduino Program
address = 0x04

def readLong():
   block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 0) 
   #second arg is 'cmd'. It is mandatory but not used in this case. 
   #It may be used by the higher level protocol
   # block is a list of 32 elements (int)
   #return block
   n = struct.unpack('<l', ''.join([chr(i) for i in block[:4]]))[0]
   return n

while True:
   time.sleep(1)
   number = readLong()
   print "[Arduino]", number, "mm"
```

And Here is the Arduino Code:

```
    #include <Wire.h>

int SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x04;
int ledPin = 3;
int analogPin = A0;

boolean ledOn = false;

void setup() 
{
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
    //Wire.onReceive(processMessage);
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  delay(500);
}

void requestEvent()
{
  long d;
  d=300259; // mockup value, in the real script is acquired by the sensor
  //Serial.println(d);
  Wire.write((const uint8_t*)&d, sizeof(long));
}
```

Thanks You!

Answer (score 1):

It's converting the first four bytes received by read_i2c_block_data() to a long assuming the data is stored most significant byte first.

I guess read_i2c_block_data() returns a list rather than a string.  If it returned a string I'd use the more natural

```py
n = struct.unpack('I', block[:4])
```

The `''.join([chr(i) for i in block[:4]])` invocation appears to be a "clever" way (which exponents call Pythonic) of converting a list to the string needed by unpack.

Answer (score 1):

When you move to python3

```
def readLong():
    return int.from_bytes(bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 0, 4), byteorder='big', signed=True)
```

if it turns out to be little endian swap 'big' for 'little'
You might want to move to smbus2 as it is more up to date